# How to replace linefeed into nothing using repl.bat in a BATCH file

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to use [REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) to delete the linefeed found in the file.

Now I have this code

```
Type "C:\user\AllFiles\%%a.in.tmp"  | C:\user\bat\repl.bat "%%s" "%%t" X > "C:\user\AllFiles\%%a.out.tmp"




%%s - Can be found in the first column of replace.txt
%%t - Can be found in the second column of replace.txt
```

Note that that below example matches pattern starts with AAA+any 3 chars and replaced with XXXYYY

```
AAA\d{3}     XXXYYY
```

Now how will I implement replacing the \R with NULL?

Comment: Null is usually `\0`. I guess you mean replace with nothing ? For windows files, the regex would be find `(?:\r\n)+` replace with `nothing`. Alternatively the regex could be `(?:\r?\n)+`. You mean line-breaks right?

Comment: @sln

Yes replace nothing. So what will be my parameter for column1 and 2 in replace.txt?

Comment: What regex engine are you using ?

Comment: @sln

Im using the repl.bat

Comment: I never used that engine before, don't think I can help.

Comment: Where that `repl.bat` come from?

Comment: @JosefZ - see first line of edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

**LineBreaks**

```
filter fix {lf|cr}
```

Fixes problems with line endings.

Lines are broken at the line feed character. If preceded by a carriage return both are removed. However a single carriage return without a line feed does not break the line.

```
cr - removes all stray CR and LF left on each line.

lf - add a LF to any CR embeded in the middle of the line.
```

It then writes the line with a CRLF at the end (the writeline method adds it).

**Example**
Fixes win.ini, not that it needs fixing, and sends it to the screen

```
filter fix cr <"%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

You'll have to modify script as it expects command line arguments.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout

    If Arg(1) = "cr" then 
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
            Line=Replace(Line, vbcr, "")
            Line=Replace(Line, vblf, "")
            outp.writeline Line
        Loop
    End If
    If Arg(1) = "lf" then 
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            Line=Inp.readline
            Line=Replace(Line, vbcr, vbcrlf)
            outp.writeline Line
        Loop
    End If
```

To use you need to run with cscript.

```
cscript //nologo c:\scriptname.vbs fix cr <inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt
```

I'm sure you can modify it. Regular Expressions are overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information for anyone to provide the full answer.

In general, you must use the `M` (multi-line) option if you want to manipulate `\n` (linefeed).

The following will remove all `\r\n` and/or `\n` from a file. Adapt as needed.

```
type file.txt|repl "\r?\n" "" m >out.txt
```